# Iterate through N number of input boxes, updating each to their max value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to give a bunch of inputs the same ID, and then iterate over them, when a checkbox is checked, and update their respective values to the MAX attribute? For example, with the following HTML:

```
CHECK ALL: <input type="checkbox" id="someIDname">
<input type="number" max="80" id="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="90" id="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="99" id="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="65" id="unrelated">
<input type="number" max="75" id="unrelated">
```

... and the JS is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someIDname').click(function(event) {  

        if(this.checked) {

            $('#anotherIDname').each( function() {
                var maxValue = $("#anotherIDname").attr("max");
                document.getElementById("anotherIDname").value = maxValue;
            });

        }

    });

});
</script>
```

I'd like to, when the checkbox is checked, have it fill in all of the MAX attributes from anything with the "anotherIDname" ID. (I'd then have three boxes, onewith 80, one with 90, one with 99. The other two are different IDs, so it would leave those alone.)

Total beginner with JS / jQuery here...  The above script works on the 1st box, but does not update the others with the "anotherIDname" ID.  (I thought maybe that ".each" would make it do them all, one at a time, but ... I guess that's not how it works. (I'm more of a PHP guy, normally, and that would be how something like this *could maybe* work if it was server-side.)  Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: `id` should be unique; use `class` when you want to give the same identifier to more than one element. elements can also have more than one class, eg `class="foo bar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong

1. `id` is always unique in the page.Same `class` is assigned to elements having same features
2. You should use `$(this).val()` to set the value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someIDname').click(function(event) {  

        if(this.checked) {

            $('.anotherIDname').each( function() {
                var maxValue = $(this).attr("max");
                console.log(maxValue);
                $(this).val(maxValue) 
            });

        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="someIDname">
<input type="number" max="80" class="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="90" class="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="99" class="anotherIDname">
<input type="number" max="65" class="unrelated">
<input type="number" max="75" class="unrelated">
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  All great answers / solutions!   I accepted this one simply because it worked w/ the fewest mods to the existing code.  (I actually meant to use classes instead of IDs... just lost my brain for a minute, there.)

Answer (score 0):

Added a class name and used querySelectorAll. Does this work as you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someIDname').click(function(event) {  

        if(this.checked) {
          document.querySelectorAll('.max').forEach(a => {
            a.value = a.max;
          });
        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
CHECK ALL: <input type="checkbox" id="someIDname">
<input type="number" max="80" id="anotherIDname" class="max">
<input type="number" max="90" id="anotherIDname" class="max">
<input type="number" max="99" id="anotherIDname" class="max">
<input type="number" max="65" id="unrelated" class="max">
<input type="number" max="75" id="unrelated" class="max">
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I actually wanted it to only apply to a specific ID (or, really a class).  But, I'm glad to know this approach as well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem exactly what do you want it to do, we can fix ?

Comment: No worries, Bibberty. I have it functional already. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` must be unique in the page. So, you can't use same id in several places. However, you can use same class in several places.

So, you'll need to change the id to class for eg.:

```
<input type="number" max="80" class="maxinput" />
```

And to set the [value](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) from max attribute:

```
$('.maxinput').val(function() { 
  return $(this).attr('max') 
});
```

However, I would suggest to use `data-*` instead of simple attribute:

```
<input type="number" data-max="80" class="maxinput" />
```

And get the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) value:

```
$('.maxinput').val(function() { 
  return $(this).data('max') 
});
```

But I am still in surprise why you aren't simply setting their values initially?

```
<input type="number" class="maxinput" value="80" />
```

Comment: Appreciate the response there!  I'm gonna retrofit this code into an older script that already has normal max attributes. So, I'm gonna stick w/ those. But, thanks for the ideas! :-)

Comment: A little bit surprises to me! How you change those ids to class?